# Haskell stack test cabal file inro not found

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghci

I got this message after trying to run stack test. Now I don't know what to do

```
Cabal file info not found for tasty-1.4.2@sha256:b124f1f5db8291e547254e3b52e94e091fb020b97421c6824fcb9df3a9d143a8,2688, updating
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Downloading timestamp
Downloading snapshot
Updating index
Updated package index downloaded
Calculating hashes to check for hackage-security rebases or filesystem changes
Updating preexisting cache, should be quick
Populating cache from file size 758210048, hash d9e9e96ff1be29ca3c6fae6f90872ab2725a89e0d5184a2c1755b5fe9bfb8ea1
Populating package index cache ...
Failed populating package index cache
BadChecksum 0
```

Comment: What happens when you re-run the command? If that `tasty` version is specified in your `extra-deps`, maybe try removing the `@sha256...` part. There might be a typo in the hash.